# FileNotFoundException when launching new asp.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to aspnet mvc. I created a new asp.net mvc (core 2.1) project in Visual Studio 2017. I removed the wwwroot folder and got rid of all the views because the purpose of this project is only to serve data via controllers (does this make sense?).

I created a really simple controller containing a simple method and the solution builds fine. But when I start it, the browser shows

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Where MyProject is the name of my project. What should I look at?

Comment: if you create an "empty" project you won't have this issue

Comment: Go to Your Project -> Properties -> Web -> Start Action -> select "Dont open a page. Wait for a request from an external application." I had to do this myself, today already.

Comment: @AussieJoe there is no 'web' section in my project properties

Comment: @MIKE if I just want web service support which type of project should I create? Should I still use the model / controller stuff or something else?

Comment: You can use web api for your solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api .  It uses model-controller architecture, without views.

Comment: @Erix i only do web api so no views. I create an empty project but I use Web Api project to copy the startup.cs into my empty project. I also need to create appsetting.json and everything else is the same

Comment: @user10803081 web api is old, use .net core it is beast

Comment: @user1080381 your link shows different framework being used. he is talking about .net core

Comment: i tried the same and it workes just fine with a basic controller. can you update question with what you have done in your controller?